# jQuery plugin with extend doesn't take user params

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, extend

I'm writing a jQuery plugin that makes containers (e.g. a div) of a hyperlink clickable.

I would like it for the user to be able to change some basic parameters.

However I must be doing something wrong, because it always uses the default param and not the user defined one.

I try the overrule the cursor.

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJkAu/24/).

The code:

```
(function($){
 $.fn.clickablecontainer = function() {
    return this.each(function(options) {

        var defaults = {  
            cursor: 'pointer',
            hoverclass: 'hover',
            activeclass: 'active'
            //ellipsisText: "..."  
        };  
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);          
        var elem = $(this);
        elem.css('cursor', options.cursor);
        $('a', elem).css('cursor', options.cursor);        

        elem.hover(function() {
            elem.addClass(options.hoverclass);
        }, function() {
            elem.removeClass(options.hoverclass);
        });

        elem.mousedown(function() {
            elem.addClass(options.activeclass);
        });

        $('body').mouseup(function() {
            elem.removeClass(options.activeclass);
        });        

        elem.click(function() {            
            var target = $('a', elem).attr('target');
            var href = $('a', elem).attr('href');            
            switch(target) {
                case '':
                case '_self':                    
                    location.href = href;
                    break;
                case '_blank':
                    window.open(href);
                    break;
                case '_parent':
                    parent.location.href = href;
                    break;
                case '_top':
                    top.location.href = href;
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('frame');
                    top.frames[target].location = href;
            }
        });
    });
 };
})(jQuery);

$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.container div').clickablecontainer({
        cursor: 'help'
    });
});
```

Finished product (special thanks to tvanfosson :) ):
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8ZaK/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two definitions of options, since you use `var` to redeclare it.  I suspect this results in the options on the right-hand side being an empty object. It would be better to simply use:

```
  options = $.extend({},defaults,options);
```

This will keep defaults intact, yet allow the values in options to override them, then reassign to the original options variable.

You also need to move the definition of the options to the outer function, otherwise you aren't actually getting any values.

```
$.fn.clickablecontainer = function(options) {
    var defaults = {  
        cursor: 'pointer',
        hoverclass: 'hover',
        activeclass: 'active'
        //ellipsisText: "..."  
    };  
    options = $.extend({},defaults, options);  

    return this.each(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        ...
```

Comment: Two things: 1. won't that make options a global? (if possible I would like to prevent that for obvious reasons) and 2. it still doesn't work :P

Comment: -EDIT- 1 is not the case when i think about it cause it is already declared right?

Comment: @PeeHaa - yep, because it's a function parameter, it's already local to the function.

Comment: @tvanfosson Thanks mate. and for #2 any ideas as to why it still doesn't work? (updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AJkAu/33/)

Comment: @Peehaa - ahh, the options parameter and extension need to be in the outer function, not the inner:  http://jsfiddle.net/qJmnJ/

Comment: OMG totally looked over that one. Thanks mate. Will post the finished product later today :)